# CSS Styles conflict

Tags: css, inline, css-tables

I have a website created by a designer entirely in a table format. I am embedding another table within its cell, the thing is my table has its own stylesheet. When I link mine externally, the entire site get warped. All I want is my Stylesheet to work on my table.

How do I include this stylesheet without causing a conflict or override on the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no better option, then give your `table` an `id` or specific `class`. Then use this in all your CSS declarations, ensuring the styles within will apply to only your new table. [This article](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070321/css-practice-pseudo-namespaces-in-complex-projects/) explains the idea of *pseudo-namespacing* further, which is worth considering.

So instead of:

```
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

You would have, e.g.:

```
.myClass td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of things to take care of: 1) preventing your style sheet from affecting the table used for formatting the entire table, and 2) preventing the formatting of that table from affecting your table. Your style sheet must be modified for this.

Start from assigning a unique `id` to your table and then using the corresponding selector in all rules of your stylesheet (see Rob W’s answer). This suffices for 1). It mostly suffices for 2), too, but not always. You should test it and have a look at the overall style sheet. There is no quick way here.

To illustrate the problematic point, suppose that you want your table to have borders around cells. For this you could have `table#foo td { border: solid; }`. But if the overall style sheet has `td { border: none !important; }`. That’s not good practice, but such things are used; authors often use `!important` for no good reason. In this case, if the overall style sheet cannot be changed, you would need to use `!important` in your style sheet, too. In extreme cases, you might even need to use `!important` *and* write selectors so that they are more specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this in-depth answer, will surely consider this!